# Do not repeat the number randomly

Tags: javascript

I just learn Javascript, I need to do so that would be generated one new number does not repeat the previous generated . Here is the code that is written , tell me what to do in these signs " ??????? ".

```
var da = randomInteger(1, 10);

function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
    rand = Math.round(rand);

    return rand; 
} 

var data = da;
var a  = [ ];

a  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));

if a.includes(data) {
    ???????????????
} else  {
    a.push(da);
}

alert(a);     

localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: Where you define your `aea`?

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki sorry fix

Answer (score 0):

I have placed your number finding login in a function and if number repeats, run same function again.
Try the following code:

```js
var arr = [];
var count = 0;

function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
}

function findNumber(){
    var da = randomInteger(1, 10);
    if(arr.indexOf(da)>=0){
        if(count <10)
   findNumber();
        else
            console.log("All permutations completed");
    }
    else{
        arr.push(da);
        count++;
    }
}

for(var i=0;i<10; i++)
 findNumber();

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I need to receive repeated "da", the array to check was this number or not

Comment: I have already done that. `FindNumber` will check if number is unique then push it to array else loop back to find a unique number.